# Combine PHP prepared statments with LIKE

Tags: php, sql-like

Anyone know how to combine PHP prepared statements with LIKE? i.e.

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE %?%";`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The % signs need to go in the variable that you assign to the parameter, instead of in the query.

I don't know if you're using mysqli or PDO, but with PDO it would be something like:

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?");
$st->execute(array('%'.$test_string.'%'));
```

For `mysqli` user the following.

```
$test_string = '%' . $test_string . '%';
$st->bind_param('s', $test_string);
$st->execute();
```

Comment: Isn't it a kind of SQL injection? It is supposed to be prevented by the prepared statement am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the concatenation operator of your respective sql database:

```
# oracle
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%' || :param || '%'
# mysql
SELECT * from table WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :param, '%')
```

I'm not familar with other databases, but they probably have an equivalent function/operator.

Comment: That won't work with strings.  It will throw warnings about non-integers.

Comment: He's probably coming from an Oracle background, that's the Oracle concatenation operator, but in MySQL it's the OR operator. In MySQL you'd have to do CONCAT('%', ?, '%')

Comment: ah, noted!  I haven't used mysql in years.

Comment: NEVER trust any value you put in your sql, even if you really think it is. This is the most obvious solution, because no preparing of the value outside the SQL, so principle of using parameters to prevent sql injection remains. You MUST trust your SQL, not your values. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%',?),'%')"
```

Answer (score 1):

in PHP using MYSQLI you need to define a new parameter which will be declared as:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?");
$newParameter='%'.$query.'%';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newParameter);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

this works for me..

Answer (score 0):

For me working great, I've looked for answer hours, thx.

```
    $dbPassword = "pass";
    $dbUserName = "dbusr";
    $dbServer = "localhost";
    $dbName = "mydb";

    $connection = new mysqli($dbServer, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    if($connection->connect_errno)
    {
        exit("Database Connection Failed. Reason: ".$connection->connect_error);
    }
        $tempFirstName = "reuel";
    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, pen_name FROM authors WHERE first_name LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%',?),'%')";
    //echo $sql;

    $stateObj = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stateObj->bind_param("s",$tempFirstName);
    $stateObj->execute();
    $stateObj->bind_result($first,$last,$pen);
    $stateObj->store_result();

    if($stateObj->num_rows > 0) {
        while($stateObj->fetch()){
            echo "$first, $last \"$pen\"";
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }

    $stateObj->close();
    $connection->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just adapt Chad Birch's answer for people like me who are used to utilize `bindValue(...)` for PDO:

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE :name");
$st->bindValue(':name','%'.$name.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can do it like this using prepared statements.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (TABLE_COLUMN LIKE CONCAT('%', :SEARCH_TEXT, '%')) OR (ANOTHER_TABLE_COLUMN LIKE CONCAT('%', :SEARCH_TEXT, '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The sprintf can do it. Remember to put another % in front of the original % to escape it.

`$ret = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE %%%s%%", $name);`