# PHP Redbean not processing tokens properly?

Tags: php, redbean

Ok, look at this code:

```
    // Query building!
    $query_params = array();
    $query = ' ';

    if (!empty($data['estado'])) {
        $query .= 'estado = ? AND ';
        $query_params[] = $data['estado'];
    }

    if (!empty($data['ref'])) {
        $query .= 'ref LIKE "%?%" AND ';
        $query_params[] = $data['ref'];
    }
```

On the first if block, we append to the query 'estado = ?', and redbeans runs it just fine. However, when I do LIKE "%?%", redbean can't simply recognize the token, and this is the error I get:

Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
File: /home/imovelli/public_html/Components/Redbean/rb.php
Line: 267

I've searched but couldn't find, is there any specific way of querying for a substring in redbeans?

Comment: show us the full query used

Comment: Here's the full code along with outputs.
http://pastebin.com/dPdV94pC

Comment: If it is anything like a normal prepare, you'd do this: `$query .= 'ref LIKE ? AND ';  $query_params[] = '%'.$data['ref'].'%';`. Don't know redbean though, so I don't know if it works that way too.

Comment: @Wrikken that was actually the right way of doing it. Could you please post you comment as an answer?

Comment: Well, if it's the same to you, and this is just about prepared statements, I'd rather close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661160/combine-php-prepared-statments-with-like :)