# How to do a form with prepared statement using LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with how to do a search script with `prepare` statement of php, Can you please guide me?

I have tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661160/combine-php-prepared-statments-with-like) but for some reason doesn't work when use the `LIMIT` function.

Below is my current script and I have these issue:

> *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10' at line 4'
>   in C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php:36 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php(36):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php on line 36*

I have edited this question taking your sugestions but I don't know what happend.

**php code:**

```
$maxRows = 10;
$pageNum = 0;
$startRow = $pageNum * $maxRows;
$sqlq = "SELECT ent_entrenamientos.id, ent_entrenamientos.descripcion, ent_entrenamientos.duracion, ent_instructores.proveedor, CONCAT(ent_instructores.nombre_pila, ' ', ent_instructores.apellido_paterno ) AS instructor, ent_entrenamientos.vencimiento, ent_tipos.descripcion AS tipo_entrenamiento, ent_entrenamientos.nivel_alerta  FROM ent_entrenamientos
   LEFT JOIN ent_instructores ON ent_entrenamientos.ent_instructor_id = ent_instructores.id
   LEFT JOIN ent_tipos ON ent_entrenamientos.ent_tipo_id = ent_tipos.id
    WHERE ent_entrenamientos.borrado_logico = FALSE AND ent_entrenamientos.descripcion LIKE :descripcion LIMIT :startow :maxrows ";
 $stmtq = $DB_con->prepare($sqlq);
 $stmtq->bindValue(':descripcion', "%$descripcion%", \PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmtq->bindValue(':startrow', $startRow, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmtq->bindValue(':maxrows', $maxRows, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmtq->execute();
```

I apreaciate your help in advance

Comment: can use LIKE :var , then just assign the $var = %$var$% prior

Comment: Thank you for answer, but Where can I type this? `within bindParam`

Comment: Just like normal bind `:var` in the query, but prior to your bindParam do `$var = "%".$var."%";`

Comment: I have already done that, but doesn´t work, I edited my question just I added the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$statement->bindValue(':description', "%$var%", \PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This will do the work for you. basically bindValue will sanitise the string and while using like we give the data as string ( like '%test%').

And rather then using sprintf you can directly write the query and bing the required values.

```
$query = "select * from <table name> where descripcion LIKE :descripcion limit :limit :offset";
$statement = $DB_con->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':description', "%{$var}%", \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':limit', $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':offset', $offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you Ratan, I am trying to follow your advice but How can I define the `$limit` var if in your example is `PARAM_INT` Can I do this? `$limit = $startRow." ".$maxRows;`

Comment: Already I understand how to define the `:limit` and `offset`, I did this whitin query I have `... LIKE :description LIMIT :limit :offset` **but** I have an issue... _Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php(36): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\training\modules\training\index7.php on line 36_

Comment: Do you please have any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: I have updated my question :)

Comment: Thank you @Ratan I have already seen what was the mistake just I will add a comma `WHERE ent_entrenamientos.borrado_logico = FALSE AND ent_entrenamientos.descripcion LIKE :descripcion LIMIT :startrow, :maxrows` inside of my query. Kind Regards!

Comment: This resolve my issue