# multiple terms SQL with explode/implode and PHP PDO

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, pdo, search-engine

I have a search form that would like the users to search multiple terms. I'm currently using PHP PDO and I'm still learning... I was wondering if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    $varSearch = @$_GET['dms']; 
    $varTerm = explode(" ", $varSearch);
    $termArray = array();
    foreach($varTerm as $term){
        $term = trim($term);
        if(!empty($term)){
            $termArray[] = "name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR tags LIKE '%".$term."%'";
        }
    }
    $implode = implode(' OR ', $termArray);
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ?");
    $sql->execute(array($implode));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement-in-php)

Comment: thanks, i answered my own question, and posted it in case anyone else needs it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else needs this answer too...

```
$varSearch = @$_GET['dms']; 
$varTerm = explode(" ", $varSearch);
$termArray = array();
foreach($varTerm as $term){
    $term = trim($term);
    if(!empty($term)){
        $termArray[] = "name LIKE :term OR tags LIKE :term";
    }
}
$implode = implode(' OR ', $termArray);
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$implode."");
$sql->execute(array(":term"=>"%".$term."%"));
```

Comment: You're only searching your database for one term.

Comment: am i not doing it in an array? I don't understand. Why am I getting a negative...

Comment: No, you're preparing a really long statement where you re-use the exact same parameter name, and then bind one parameter to it.  You're getting a downvote because your answer is wrong.

Comment: actually I just checked what my array outputs, and I believe my solution is the correct one....

Comment: Say if I type in term1 and term2, then it would search `name LIKE term1 OR tags LIKE term1 OR name like term2 OR tags LIKE term2`... this which gives people the ability to search two different terms going through name table and tags table

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered doing something like this, instead:

```
$varSearch = @$_GET['dms'];
$varTerm = explode(" ", $varSearch);
$termsStringArray = array();
$termsArray = array();
foreach($varTerm as $term){
    $term = trim($term);
    if(!empty($term)) {
        array_push($termsStringArray, "name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? ");
        array_push($termsArray, $term);
        array_push($termsArray, $term);  // note, you can do this part differently, if you'd like
    }
}
$implodedTermsString = implode('OR ', $termsStringArray);
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM biz WHERE " . $implodedTermsString);
$sql->execute(array($termsArray));
```

Output:

```
// prepare statement
SELECT * FROM biz WHERE name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ?

// $termsArray (for execute)
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => this
    [2] => is
    [3] => is
    [4] => the
    [5] => the
    [6] => string
    [7] => string
)
```

Basically, trying to separate the array data from the initial SQL query `prepare` string.  Let me know if that works for you!

Though, you still will want to do some sort of checking (or sanitization,) of the data you are getting from the `$_GET` variable.  That `$_GET` variable could have anything in it... and could be bad for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or other unwanted issues.

And, `LIKE` isn't necessarily going to be the most efficient way to do this type of database search.  But if you use it (and I have used it for search things in the past,) try checking out: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning.

Comment: I thought the `prepare` was insusceptible to SQL injection?

Comment: I must have updated this while you were writing your comment... :)  It's usually good to sanitize your data before it goes into something that will be used with the database. (http://diovo.com/2008/09/sanitizing-user-data-how-and-where-to-do-it/)

Comment: Thanks, also.. isn't my answer below the same? putting it into an array?

Comment: Kind of like @Brad hinted at in his later comment, I believe that your earlier answer is still going to end up searching for the same `:term`... because `:term` is ultimately the only key in your array at the end of the code, right? :)  The alternate answer I gave should go through all of the terms you are searching for because all of the terms are in a separate array (`termsArray `)... and the `prepare` string (`implodedTermsString `) just uses `?` for each of those separate array values.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array,`

Comment: That's weird; I double-checked my code just now... and `$termsArray = array();` does mean that `$termsArray` is an `array`... so when `array_push()` is being used with `$termsArray` (or even `$termsStringArray`,) that `parameter 1` is, indeed, an array.  Any idea what version of PHP you are using?  I tested this on PHP 5.2.17 (from the command line.)

Comment: I've checked my code and I'm outputting different values, and not the same. the two `:terms` I have goes through two different tables, `name` and `tags`, so if I'm searching `term1`, it will go through table `name` and `tags` that has `term1`. Let me know if this make sense?

Comment: Here is the output I'm getting for the SQL in your code from your answer: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE :term OR tags LIKE :term OR name LIKE :term OR tags LIKE :term OR name LIKE :term OR tags LIKE :term OR name LIKE :term OR tags LIKE :term`  And then, when you do `$sql->execute(array(":term"=>"%".$term."%"));` you are only searching for the one term.  If you had this inside a loop, to iterate through all of the earlier-found terms... then it would probably work.  But as it is, like @Brad said, it appears that you are only looking for one term...!

Comment: That SQL is correct, it does output that, but you're forgetting the explode and the foreach. When I type in multiple words, it does a foreach getting each word, and then putting it into an array, so each term will go through a `name` and `tag` table

Answer (score 1):

Remake

```
$my_explode = explode(" ",$search);
$query = array();
foreach($my_explode as $string)
{
$query[] ="name LIKE '%".$string."%' OR email LIKE '%".$string."%'";
}
$implode = implode(' OR ', $query);
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM _table WHERE ".$implode."") as $info)
{
    echo $info['name']."<br />";
}
```

Secure for injection, with php retrieve just alphanumeric chars

```
$search = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "-", $_GET["text"]);
```