# implement LIKE query in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I am running problems in implementing LIKE in PDO

I have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE '%?%' OR address LIKE '%?%'";
$params = array($var1, $var2);
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

I checked the `$var1` and `$var2` they contain both the words I want to search, my PDO is working fine since some of my queries `SELECT` `INSERT` they work, it's just that I am not familiar in `LIKE` here in PDO.

The result is none returned. Do my `$query` is syntactically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You have to include the `%` signs in the `$params`, not in the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?";
$params = array("%$var1%", "%$var2%");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

If you'd look at the generated query in your previous code, you'd see something like `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE '%"foo"%' OR address LIKE '%"bar"%'`, because the prepared statement is quoting your values inside of an already quoted string.

Comment: +1 for the explanation.. But I don't think there is a way to look at the generated query.. is there anything like that?

Comment: Couldn't figure this out for the life of me and I had forgotten all about this. Awesome answer. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if my parameter is "$name%" and the user enters: $name = '%bob'. Wouldn't that have the unintended side effect of an anchored search instead of a left anchored search? How would I prevent this?

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE CONCAT('%', :var1, '%')
            OR address LIKE CONCAT('%', :var2, '%')";

$ar_val = array(':var1'=>$var1, ':var2'=>$var2);
if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) { ... }
```

Comment: This is slower than adding the % directly to the binded variables.

Answer (score 5):

No,  you don't need to quote prepare placeholders. Also, include the % marks inside of your variables.

```
LIKE ?
```

And in the variable: `%string%`

Comment: Hmm, pardon but I'm not quite sure how to implement what you have just suggested.

Comment: I'm on mobile but I'll try to explain the best I can. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?";
$params = array("%$var1%", "%$var2%");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see below example

```
$title = 'PHP%';
$author = 'Bobi%';
// query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title like ? AND author like ? ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$author));
```

Hope it will work.