# PHP PDO prepare throwing exception when using "%"

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

The following line throws an exception -

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE name LIKE %:name%");
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "%": syntax error'

Taking the % signs out gets rid of the error, but obviously the search doesn't work as I want it.  I've tried toying with quotes, putting in an actual value instead of the :-prefixed PDO variable, the only thing that gets rid of the error is removing the % signs.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo

Comment: @RoyalBg, that SO actually didn't help me at all.  My parameters come straight from the $_POST, and modifying that didn't seem like a good solution.  Knittl's answer of putting the % signs in quotes in the query and concatenating them with || was the exact answer I needed.

Comment: you didn't mention that in the beginning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator takes a string:

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE name LIKE '%' + :name + '%'");
```

Note that an empty `:name` will match everything (`'%%'`)

Sqlite uses `||` to concatenate strings, so `'%' || :name || '%'` should do.

Another way (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo)) is to add the percent signs to the value of your param. So you'd have a query `LIKE :name` and then before binding the parameter, add the percent signs: `$name = '%'.$name.'%'; $sth->execute(array('name' => $name));`

Comment: Thanks!  This worked!  I'd actually say this is probably my best experience with stackoverflow to date.  After several hours banging my head against the desk, to get a workable answer in the first two minutes after posting the question.  If only it didn't make me wait 15 minutes before being allowed to check your answer as "accepted".