# PDO - If in foreach loop always returns too else

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

What I am trying to achieve is make a page where there is an alphabet and when you click on a letter in the alphabet, you will get the value thats in the column in the database.

An example if you didn't understand it.

Database:

```
John
Jason
Jos
Jan
Marco
Bott
```

So I click on a letter in the alphabet:

```
<a href="?tag=J">J</a>
```

This should give me all the users starting with J.

This is my code which doesnt work (it always returns too else).

```
            if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
                $tag = $_GET['tag'];
                $check = range('A', 'Z');
                foreach($check as $row){
                    if($tag == $row){
                        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users WHERE UPPER(names) LIKE '{$row}%'");
                    } else {
                        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Read more about `prepare`.

Comment: The problem is with **LIKE** see this [ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo/11117213#11117213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick bugfix.

```
if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
    $tag = $_GET['tag'];
    $check = range('A', 'Z');
    // default query
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users");
    foreach($check as $row){
        if($tag == $row){
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users WHERE UPPER(names) LIKE '{$row}%'");
            // do not check other
            break; 
        } 
    }
}
```

But it is wrong way. You do not need `foreach`.

```
if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
    $tag = $_GET['tag'];
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $tag, $matches)){
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users WHERE UPPER(names) LIKE '{$matches[0]}%'");
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT names FROM users");
        }
}
```

Comment: What other way is there without using foreach.