# LIKE query not working PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

LIKE query not working,
it just output blank.

[image]

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country=:c LIKE '%m%'");
$stmt->bindValue(":c", "malaysia", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Possibly this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo

Comment: you need a `OR` or `AND` between `=` and `LIKE` and a column to match for the `LIKE`

Comment: Try the solution proposed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL-Syntax is wrong, not sure what you want to obtain, but correct would be:

```
SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country LIKE '%' || :c || '%';


--OR

SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country  = :c  AND <your_column_here> LIKE '%m%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country=:c LIKE '%m%'");
```

to

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country LIKE '%m%'");
```

You are either comparing values with the LIKE function or comparing with the variable ':c'. Its one or the other.

If you want to use both change to:

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE h_country=:c OR  h_country LIKE '%m%'");
```