# PDO bindParam not replacing multiple instances

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a search function for my site and would like to search in the title and content of the articles.

The query would look like `SELECT id FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%<user input>%' OR content LIKE '%<user input>%';`

Is there any way to achieve this with PDO? As I've read, the following is not possible.

```
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mysite', username, password);
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :userinput OR content LIKE :userinput');
$search = '%' . $_REQUEST[searchterm] . '%';
$statement->bindParam(':userinput', $search);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implement LIKE query in PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem binding multiple variables at the same time, I haven't tested it, but this should work (just change the syntax to using colons and no spaces) :

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :userinput OR content LIKE :userinput');
$search = '%' . $_REQUEST[searchterm] . '%';
$statement->bindParam(':userinput', $search);
```

Comment: No I've found it. It should be `bindValue(':userinput', $search)`

Comment: @WardSegers If you are altering `$search` after binding it, yes, it should be bindValue. Glad you found it.