# : syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 16

Tags: php

```
$query = "select * from login details where User_id like '$user_name' and Password '$user_pass'";
```

I cannot find any error but it showing error.

Comment: Unless `$user_name` contains `%` there's no reason to use `like` here. One error I can spot is the missing `=` after `Password` - which is most likely not the cause for the error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some more lines of code before and after that line 16. And take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which you should have done when registering

Comment: Using `like` to match a user name sounds like an easy hack to get round, plus you should look into using `password_hash` rather than storing plain passwords in the database (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) AND use prepared statements (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Small side note: Try not to use like if you don't use a wildcard when you want to do a comparison like in your example.  For different reasons. Performance, possible errors etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336940/14807111

Comment: Can You share your code from line 1 to the line 16, please?

Answer (score 0):

Please stop execute queries as native call, your query have `SQL INJECTION`, you can execute queries with PDO like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE User_id LIKE ? AND Password = ?";
$params = array("%$user_name%", "$user_pass");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

[REF LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo)

[REF LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Also please prevent check `UserId` column as like on query and `Password` column without hash value.

Comment: Although good advice _in general_, why would this resolve an “unexpected ‘;’” syntax error?

Comment: when ``$user_name`` or ``$password`` contain ``'`` character query after parsing will be bad string,  also please check before line code from query line.

Comment: While your statement is correct, this won't result in a syntax error but a SQL error during runtime

Comment: replace your query code with this: ``$query = "select * from login details where User_id like %"+$user_name+"% and Password="+$user_pass+""`` dont need ``'`` character between ``"`` duble quotation.

Comment: Unsure what you are saying, but the code OP posted is *not* the problem here - [demo](https://ideone.com/SeKHD2)