# what is the correct PDO syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement-in-php)

My sql statement initially was like this:

```
"SELECT companyname, axiscategory 
FROM axispl WHERE companyname 
LIKE '$searchterm%' LIMIT 11"
```

Now I want to change this to PDO format.  Doubt I have is regarding the wild cards I have used in the searchterm (anything starting with...).  How do I achieve this in PDO form?

I wrote the code till WHERE.  Then when it came to writing companyname = : ... I was stuck.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT companyname, axiscategory 
FROM axispl WHERE companyname 
LIKE '$searchterm%' LIMIT 11");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statement are useful because they separate the query and the parameters. Concatenation is now something to forget.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT companyname, axiscategory 
    FROM axispl WHERE companyname 
    LIKE :searchterm LIMIT 11");

$query->bindValue('searchterm',$searchterm.'%');
$query->execute();
//then to fetch the results
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here I used named parameters as they are more readable, but you can also use indexed parameters like that :

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT companyname, axiscategory 
    FROM axispl WHERE companyname 
    LIKE ? LIMIT 11");

$query->bindValue(1,$searchterm.'%');
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT companyname, axiscategory
                       FROM axispl
                       WHERE companyname LIKE ?
                       LIMIT 11");
```

Then you execute it using `$query->execute(array($searchterm.'%'));`