# Silex repository SQL escaping single quote issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, repository, silex

Maybe a noob question but I have to ask...

This is the query I need:

```
select title from internships where title like '% someParameter %'
```

I have to use this in my Repository in my Silex project, so I wrote a function in my repo:

```
public function getTitleQuery($title) {
    return $this->db->fetchAll('select title from internships where title like \'% ? %\' ', array($title));
}
```

When I escape the single quotes like `\'` php sees the question mark as a question mark and not as a parameter.

Comment: what if you change the outer quotes to double quotes so you dont need to escape the inner quotes? ej

change 

`'select title from internships where title like \'% ? %\' '`

to

`"select title from internships where title like '% ? %' "`

Comment: It hase the same effect, the question mark remains just a question mark and not a sign for a parameter.

Comment: try this, `'select title from internships where title like ?'`  and in the array section put `array("%{$title}%")` as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement

Comment: letme put it in an answer so it does not afect your acept rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in the sql:

```
'select title from internships where title like ?'
```

and in the array section put

```
array("%{$title}%")
```

as seen in [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement)