# Constructing PHP/MySQL search query with variable options

Tags: php, mysql

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I have a SQL table that has a list of job opportunities for a client's website.

I am trying to create a search form but not all the fields will necessarily be filled in.

The possible values are:

`title` = the title of the job

`location` = the location of the job

`sal1` = the bottom bracket of the desired salary

`sal2` = the top bracket of the desired salary

**The Code**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `jobs`';

if($_GET['title']!='') $query.= ' AND `title` LIKE %'.$_GET['title'];
if($_GET['location']!='') $query.= ' AND `location`='.$_GET['location'];
if($_GET['sal1']!='') $query.= ' AND `sal1`>='.$_GET['sal1'];
if($_GET['sal2']!='') $query.= ' AND `sal2`<='.$_GET['sal2'];

$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query.' ORDER BY `date` DESC');
$stmt->execute();
```

**The Issue**

On paper this method should work, but I would prefer to use prepared statements. The only method of doing this seems to be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each `$_GET` variable, as I can't figure out how to use `execute(array($val1,$val2...))` when I don't know how many variables are in use.

If possible, how can I utilised prepared statements to sanitize the `$_GET` variables?

Comment: The `%` goes inside the quotes. Plus, you should change all `$query.=` to `$query .=` since that will break your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- *"Plus, you should change all $query.= to $query .= since that will break your query."* whatchoo talkin bout?

Comment: @Madbreaks Try it out for yourself. I don't need to, I know.

Comment: `$query.=` attempts to perform a concatenation, `$query .=` (with a space) correctly employs the operand @Madbreaks

Comment: However, the code you have Ben seems to be missing something. Your query right now, translates to `SELECT * FROM table AND column LIKE xxx  ORDER BY` unless that's only part of your actual code(?).

Comment: What on Earth are you guys talking about?

Comment: Basically two sets of ifs: one set to include or not the placeholder in the SQL before prepare. One set to bind or not the param.

Comment: @georg For one thing, `LIKE %'.$_GET` will fail. More like `LIKE '%word'` and the concatenate will fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- *"Try it out for yourself. I don't need to, I know.*".  You're not really here to help, are you?

Comment: @Madbreaks I admit I was wrong, but go over the comments under Rocket's answer which will explain it in its own right instead of me repeating it here. Please be polite, I was. ;-) and yes, I am here to help as I was right about the `%` being outside the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle variable number of query parameters by using `bindParam`:

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

Docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

**EDIT** 
To use `LIKE`: [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement)

Comment: I'm familiar with the method. Can I use `bindParam` on a variable that doesn't exist (i.e. if the user hasn't searched for  a title, by binding a value to the `:title` parameter will it still search correctly)?

Comment: Why would you do that?  The idea is, if the user did not search by title (e.g. `$_GET['title'];` is empty) then don't bind that param, nor include it in the query at all.

Comment: I see what you mean - having the query expanded (`if($_GET['location']!='') $query .= ' AND `location`=:location';`), then preparing (`$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);`) and finally binding (`if($_GET['location']!='') $stmt->bindParam(':location',$_GET['location']);`) before executing works. However, the wildcard `:title` won't work correctly with this. What is the correct method of using `LIKE` and `%` with the PDO statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `execute()` an associative array.  You just add placeholders for each value in `$_GET` you want, then pass the whole array to `execute()`

So, first you create your query string, prepare it, then call `execute()`.

P.S. You forgot the `WHERE`.  You can't use `AND` without `WHERE`.  I'd suggest building the query like this:

```
// Base query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `jobs`';

// WHERE clauses
$where = array();

// Don't concat GET values, use placeholders
if($_GET['title'] != '') $where[] = '`title` LIKE CONCAT("%", :title)';
if($_GET['location'] != '') $where[] = '`location` = :location';
if($_GET['sal1'] != '') $where[] = '`sal1`>= :sal1';
if($_GET['sal2'] != '') $where[] = '`sal2`<= :sal2';

// Combine the WHERE clauses
if(count($where) > 0) $query .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $where);

// Prepare the query
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query.' ORDER BY `date` DESC');

// Run it with the entered parameters
$stmt->execute($_GET);
```

NOTE: I'm doing `CONCAT("%", :title)` in the first clause.  This is because `LIKE` expects a string.  It wants something like `'%test'` (note how the `%` is *part* of the string).  I used `CONCAT` in MySQL instead of doing `$_GET['title'] = '%'.$_GET['title'];` in PHP.

Comment: Some don't seem to agree with my comment about `$query.=` while some have.

Comment: `$query.=` won't concatenate properly, would "you" agree? I've seen it before where OP's code failed because of not concatenating properly `$query .=`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Works fine here: https://eval.in/245783

Comment: Well I'll be a monkeys uncle. That is too bizarre. As I said, there was a question about a few weeks ago where the concatenate failed because of not having a space between. Too too weird. But why did you choose to do `$query .=` in your answer?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Personal preference.  `$query.=` looks ugly :-)

Comment: Ok. Well, I was wrong about the concatenate, but pretty sure I was right about the `LIKE %'` having the `%` outside the quote.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yeah.  The `%` should be part of the string, not outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating, which is verbose and error-prone, populate two arrays - placeholders and params - as you go, and insert all placeholders at once at the end:

```
$where  = array();
$params = array();

if(!empty($_GET['title'])) {
    $where  []= '`title` LIKE ?';
    $params []= '%' . $_GET['title'];
}

if(!empty($_GET['location'])) {
    $where  []= '`location` = ?';
    $params []= $_GET['location'];
}

// etc

if(!count($where))
    // error

$where = implode(' AND ', $where);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE $where ORDER BY `date` DESC";

$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```