# How to escape 'LIKE' statement in custom PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have a custom OOP query object with prepared statements that I use for MySQL queries. The problem is that I have a `LIKE` statement that will not allow me to insert data using a prepared statement.

How can I escape the data in this scenario? Here's my code:

```
$search_q = !empty($search) ? "AND `title` LIKE '%?%'" : "";
$items = DB::fetch("SELECT `title` FROM `products` WHERE `active` = 1 $search_q;", array($start));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the wildcard match characters in the placeholder, not in the query, so instead of doing:

```
$search = 'find this string';
$db::query("SELECT ... FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%?%' ");
```

You do:

```
$search = '%find this string%';
$db::query("SELECT ... FROM table WHERE col LIKE ? ");
```

Answer (score 0):

[First result in Google serp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement)

```
$query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ?');
$query->execute(array('value%'));
while ($results = $query->fetch())
{
    echo $results['column'];
}
```

Comment: Yes, however as shown above my DB object isn't structured like that.