# PHP prepared like-statement in function format?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a like statement in the function format. I received a lot of results using mysql or pdo formats, but they didn't work for my format i have set up already. It's just not returning anything and I am not sure if this is the correct format. Here is what I have:

```
  function search_users($namesearch){
global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE username LIKE '%:namesearch%'
                ORDER BY username";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":namesearch", $namesearch);
    $statement->execute();
    $usersearch= $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $usersearch;
}
```

Comment: You can't create a bind like this `'%:namesearch%'`. I suggest you [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/583336/2518525).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this.

```
  function search_users($namesearch){
global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE username LIKE ?
                ORDER BY username";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array('%' . $namesearch . '%'));
    $usersearch= $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $usersearch;
}
```