# Select pdo cant find the symbol like & '

Tags: php, database, pdo

PDO can't find the `&` symbol. 
My data is:

```
Fast & Furious
```

My code is:

```
$sec = $db->prepare("Select * from filmler where film_ad = ?");
$sec->bindParam(1, $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR)
```

`rowCount` resulting 0 but `$needle` is equal to "Fast & Furious".
I mean I'm actually looking for **"Fast & Furious"**.

Comment: Please add a little more detail. It is far from clear what your problem actually is

Comment: Change filter: **where film_ad LIKE ?** and use % for $needle: **$sec->bindParam(1, "%$needle%",PDO::PARAM_STR);**

Comment: Show the code where you actually execute the statement, fetch the result, and check/dump the result.

Comment: Maybe the data in database is HTML encoded.

Comment: Then the data in your database isn't what you think it is. There might be stray whitespace, unprintable characters, or the data is encoded differently than you think it is. Run `SELECT HEX(film_ad) WHERE id = ?` or similar and post the results and we can tell you what it actually is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Execute the prepared statement after binding variables.

```
$needle = 'Fast & Furious';
```

If you want to find exactly the same value as `$needle`, try this:

```
$sec = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM filmler WHERE film_ad = ?');
$sec->bindParam(1, $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sec->execute();

var_dump($sec->rowCount());
```

Or:

```
$sec = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM filmler WHERE film_ad = ?');
$sec->execute([$needle]);

var_dump($sec->rowCount());
```

If you want to use `LIKE` operator with `%` wildcard, then try [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698):

```
$needle = "%{$needle}%";

$sec = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM filmler WHERE film_ad LIKE ?');
$sec->bindParam(1, $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sec->execute();

var_dump($sec->rowCount());
```

[Or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357296):

```
$sec = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM filmler WHERE film_ad LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")');
$sec->execute([$needle]);

var_dump($sec->rowCount());
```