# search not returning query

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

Sorry my english. I'm trying to search mysql database that contains hashtags, but it returns all.

eg Search #NBA returns: #NBA, #NBA2021, #NBAscoreBoard, etc

I've tried every preg_replace on here. eg #(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)# But how do I break after the specific search is met?

```
$_GET["tag"]='#nba'; // $_GET is from a  query string

$fulltag = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", '', $_GET["tag"]); //trying to isolate this problem 

 $sql='SELECT * FROM status WHERE data LIKE "%#'.$fulltag.'%" LIMIT 12';
    // 
    //
    //
echo //the result containing the "# $fulltag";
```

Comment: Didnt we see this a couple of hours ago

Comment: Yes, but it didn't have as much code

Comment: Did you try simply `"%#'.$fulltag.'"` without the wildcard after your criteria

Comment: yes, but it expects that to be the end of the string.  If there was anything after the hashtag it was omitted from the search

Comment: Why not just do two queries, one for if `data = fullTag` and if that returns nothing, then do the wildcard search?

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment--just doing two queries with one to test if `data = fullTag`, and then if that returns nothing, then doing the wildcard search--is probably going to be simpler.

However, if you really want this to be a single query, you could do something like this, wherein you test to see if it is an exact match within a sub-query, then order by whether it's an exact match so that if there is an exact match, it will be the first result.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT 
  data,
  CASE 
    WHEN data = "#NBA"
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END AS is_exact
FROM status 
WHERE data LIKE "%#NBA%"
LIMIT 12
) AS matches
ORDER BY is_exact DESC
```

A separate note: You code right now is very vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should try using parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. See [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Here is an example of the above query using PDO, and [this method of using `CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357296/451726) to safely add wildcards to your query:

```php
$_GET["tag"]='#nba'; // $_GET is from a  query string

$fulltag = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", '', $_GET["tag"]); //trying to isolate this problem 

$pdo = new PDO(/* your connection details */);

 $sql = 
    'SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            data,
            CASE 
                WHEN data = CONCAT("#", :tag1)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS is_exact
        FROM status 
        WHERE data LIKE CONCAT("%#", :tag2, "%")
        LIMIT 12
    ) AS matches
    ORDER BY is_exact DESC
';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    ':tag1' => $fulltag,
    ':tag2' => $fulltag,
]);
```

Here's your simpler query using the same, safer approach:

```php
$_GET["tag"]='#nba'; // $_GET is from a  query string

$fulltag = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", '', $_GET["tag"]); //trying to isolate this problem 

$pdo = new PDO(/* your connection details */);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM status WHERE data LIKE CONCAT("%#", :fullTag, "%") LIMIT 12';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':fullTag' => $fulltag]);
```

Comment: I'm going to take this for a test drive. I appreciate it. There's a pile of other security things in the code, but I left them out as they distracted from the  preg_replace/match issue. Thanks